# vb Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: vb.net

Problem with database. Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

```
Dim query = "Select DISTINCT SUM(bi.[QTY]) as CountQTY From mytable..."
Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
        While reader1.Read()
            If IsDBNull(reader1) Then
                CartCountL.Text = 0
            Else
                CartCountL.Text = reader1.GetInt32(0)
            End If

        End While
```

Comment: a `SqlDataReader` is an object.  It can never be DBNull, but could be null/Nothing.

Comment: `If IsDBNull(Reader.Item(0))` or `If reader.IsDBNull(0) ` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix this finally works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will have always at least a `Row` even it is `NULL`, you should check the value. You can do it like below :

```
Dim query As SqlCommand = "Select DISTINCT SUM(bi.[QTY]) as CountQTY From mytable..."
Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = query.ExecuteReader()
CartCountL.Text = "0"

While reader1.Read()
    If IsDBNull(reader1.GetInt32(0)) = False Then
        CartCountL.Text = reader1.GetInt32(0).ToString()
    End If
End While
```

You can also handle the `NULL` in database level like below :

```
Dim query As SqlCommand = "Select DISTINCT SUM(COALESCE(bi.[QTY], 0)) as CountQTY From mytable..."
```

Then the required code would be simple :

```
While reader1.Read()
    CartCountL.Text = reader1.GetInt32(0).ToString()
End While
```

Comment: this is perfect. do you know how can i do if statment inside cartcountL?

Comment: Not clear what do you mean by `if statment inside cartcount` What's the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You should change `IsDBNull` to `IsNothing` as mentioned in comments a SqlDataReader is an object. It can never be `DBNull`, but could be `null`/`Nothing`.

```
Dim query As String = "Select DISTINCT SUM(bi.[QTY]) as CountQTY 
From mytable..."
Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
     Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(query, sqlConn)
     sqlConn.Open()
     Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
     If reader1.HasRows Then
        While reader1.Read()
            CartCountL.Text = reader1.GetInt32(0)
        End While
     Else
        CartCountL.Text = 0
     End If
     reader.Close()
 End Using
```

Comment: I have edit an answer. Please test on your application if got another error.

Comment: You are closing the barn door after the horse has escaped.  If `reader1` could be `Nothing`, checking it after you have `Read()` from it is too late.  And if there is no data for some reason, it wont enter the While block- the code to set to `"0"` (not `0`) needs to be outside that block.   Everyone needs to set `Option Strict On` because `CartCountL.Text = reader1.GetInt32(0)` is another implicit conversion

Comment: sorry still geting same error. i noticed that my sql query does return null. but not sure how to handle in reader

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to share a another way of doing if statments. i think this is good if you want to check multi cols

```
 Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
        While reader1.Read()
            CartCountL.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(reader1("CountQTY")), "0", reader1("CountQTY"))
        End While
```